# Suporte a cluster no Framework Demoiselle 2.4

Tags: jboss, demoiselle

Estou tentando subir em modo cluster uma aplicação que utiliza o *Framework Demoiselle* na versão 2.4, porém observei que o `web-fragment.xml` do `demoiselle-servlet` não possui a tag `<distributable/>`. Segundo a especificação da *servlet 3.0*, faz-se necessário que, além do web.xml, todos os web-fragments do projeto possuam a tag `<distributable/>`.
Desta forma, gostaria de saber se o *framework Demoiselle* tem suporte à clusterização com replicação de sessão.

> Ambiente: 
>   JBoss 6.1 EAP
>
> Servlet 3.0
>   Archetype Demoiselle-jsf-jpa:2.4.0

Observei que a lib `demoiselle-servlet` utilizava um `web-fragment` mas este não possuía a tag `<distributable/>`, o qual invalidava a clusterização de toda a minha aplicação. Editei o jar do demoiselle-servlet somente para fins de testes e, desta forma, constatei o correto funcionamento do cluster (a replicação de sessão funcionou!). Desta forma, fica a questão, o `Framework Demoiselle` não permite clusterização propositadamente ou essa configuração apenas passou desapercebida?